# xslt: how to select an element from a variable

Tags: xslt

For an input as below:

```
<Classes>
  <ClassOfService Cabin="Y" Status="6">S</ClassOfService>
  <ClassOfService Cabin="Y" Status="5">N</ClassOfService>
  <ClassOfService Cabin="Y" Status="1">Q</ClassOfService>
  <ClassOfService Cabin="Y" Status="0">O</ClassOfService>
  <ClassOfService Cabin="Y" Status="0">E</ClassOfService>
</Classes>
```

I want to get the first, in order of bottom to top,  ClassOfService value which has stauts >=3. So it should be N. 
I tried following in my xsl but it doesn’t work:

```
  <xsl:variable name="qualifiedClass" select="Classes/ClassOfService[@Status   >=3]"/>
<xsl:variable name="numOfqClass"  select="count(Classes/ClassOfService[@Status >=3])"/> 
<xsl:value-of select="$qualifiedClass/ClassOfService[$numOfqClass]"/>
```

how to select an element from variable?

Alternatively, I also tried below, doesn't work either.

```
<xsl:value-of select="Classes/ClassOfService[@Status>=3][last()]"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Your question is completely unclear, there is no single line of xml or xslt in it. Please edit it to contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Stefan, this is my first post and I don't know how to include code in my question. it was filtered by system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the first, in order of bottom to top, ClassOfService
>   value which has stauts >=3.

I think that "*first, in order of bottom to top*" means *last, in document order* (which is the [order](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-document-order) by which XPath operates).

So your attempt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Classes/ClassOfService[@Status >= 3][last()]"/>
```

**is** the correct answer, and it **does work** if applied from the context of the `/` root node.

---

See it working here: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuN